# How can I upgrade Magento ver. 1.3.2.4 to latest full release (1.7.0.2)?

Tags: magento

A client is running an eCommerce site with Magento ver. 1.3.2.4. Yes, it's a very old version, but they never needed updates until now.

Things are not working properly in the Magento admin - can't even create a new product - when we try that we get this error:
Unrecognized method 'useStraightJoin()'

So, perhaps a good option is to try to upgrade the system to the latest full release (ver 1.7.0.2 at this time). What do you think?

I tried downloading the package, unzipping, and then FTPing the contents to a copy of the site, then deleted the /var/cache and /var/session folders, and tried to navigate to a page hoping for the updates to compete themselves, but all I get are errors.

So, can anyone share their experience in upgrading such old Magento instances? Should I try to upgrade first to ver 1.4.1.0 and then to 1.7.0.2?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.3.2.4 was the first Magento version I've worked on and I remember having problems with an update to 1.4.1.0 even the theme wasn't working anymore and had to make some changes in the layout.

You can import your database as you would with Magento sample data before a fresh install; use magento import/export scripts or make your own custom scripts to import/export. Backup before you do anything.

I recommend making a fresh install of 1.7.0.2 (or maybe 1.8.1.0 if this will get out any time soon). After that you should check your plugins if you bought them and they are still maintained and they have a version compatible with 1.7.0.2  get/use that version. If they don't have an updated version you'll have to get a new plugin. Maybe some of them will still work as they are or with minor tweaks, but I doubt that. If you have any plugins that need to rewrite in the local folder the Mage folder (and you have app/code/local/Mage/Some_module_from_core), get rid of them because those are probably garbage and you won't be able to update your Magento.

You will have to make lots of tests to see if a plugin you use now is still compatible or not so make a backup everytime you progress further.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a new version magento uploaded,  perhaps you can consider backup the old database and import into the new magento.  However, you may have to manually backup the old database since you are having issues in the manageement

Answer (score 0):

We just did 1.4.0.1 to 1.7.0.2

Of course, the theme hardly worked. Lots of issues.

We changed server as well, and the newer PHP (5.3) caused more issues.

All the extensions needed upgrades.

Literally, it is not easy, at all.

It may be easier for you to export/import customers and export/import products/categories, and then import and debug the theme. You will lose the old orders, (no good way to export/import those) but you can export them to CSV and keep them on file.

This is probably your safest bet.